# How to reverse only hebrew chars on a string dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to reverse only hebrew chars in a string .
For example :
input: 1234 בלה בלה בלה
output': הלב הלב הלב 1234

Answer (score 0):

**Note that for the algorithm below to work you will need to manually add all the Hebrew characters to the list named `chars` I have only added the 3 Hebrew chars you specified in your example**

Note that you could populate the char `List` using a json array if you can find one online. [How to get json from the web](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)

1. Create List of Hebrew characters

```dart
  final List<String> chars = <String>[
    "ב",
    "ל",
    "ה",
  ];
```

2. Create temp String from original string with only Hebrew characters, but in reverse

```dart
    String temp = "";
    for (int i = widget.reverseString.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (chars.contains(widget.reverseString[i])) {
        temp += widget.reverseString[i];
      }
    }
```

3. Replace occurrences of Hebrew characters in original string with temp values

```dart
int tempIndex = 0;
String reveredString = widget.reverseString;
for (int r = 0; r < widget.reverseString.length; r++) {
  if (chars.contains(widget.reverseString[r])) {
    reveredString = _replaceCharAt(reveredString, r, temp[tempIndex]);
    tempIndex++;
  }
}
```

**Full Example:**

```dart
//ref:
//https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-string-without-affecting-special-characters/
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReverseHebrew extends StatefulWidget {
  final String reverseString;

  const ReverseHebrew({
    Key? key,
    required this.reverseString,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ReverseHebrewState();
  }
}

class _ReverseHebrewState extends State<ReverseHebrew> {
  /*
    This list must be manually populated to include all Hebrew characters for this
    code to properly work.
   */
  final List<String> chars = <String>[
    "ב",
    "ל",
    "ה",
  ];

  String _replaceCharAt(String oldString, int index, String newChar) {
    return oldString.substring(0, index) +
        newChar +
        oldString.substring(index + 1);
  }

  String _reverse() {
    // copy hebrew chars to temp in reverse order
    String temp = "";
    for (int i = widget.reverseString.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (chars.contains(widget.reverseString[i])) {
        temp += widget.reverseString[i];
      }
    }

    // replace occurrences of Hebrew chars in the original string with
    // the reversed values in temp
    int tempIndex = 0;
    String reveredString = widget.reverseString;
    for (int r = 0; r < widget.reverseString.length; r++) {
      if (chars.contains(widget.reverseString[r])) {
        reveredString = _replaceCharAt(reveredString, r, temp[tempIndex]);
        tempIndex++;
      }
    }

    // return reversed string
    return reveredString;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(_reverse());
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text("Original: 1234 בלה בלה בלה"),
              Text("Reversed:"),
              ReverseHebrew(
                reverseString: "בלה בלה בלה 1234",
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image: Shows output of reversing Hebrew only text]

[Ref: Geeks for Geeks Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-string-without-affecting-special-characters/)

Comment: Hi thanks for responding . My use case for this is pdf creation in flutter is not supporting hebrew so it reverse it when i create a pdf file . So I thought about reversing the string before creating the file so it will look correct . This solution is awesome but the library uses custom pdf widgets . So i need to send only the text .

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly Hebrew has the range \u0590-\u05fe (according to this [nice JavaScript Unicode Regex generator](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/js/regex#:%7E:text=0590%2D05FF,Hebrew)).

So we can use this to find and reverse Hebrew only from any given string.

Here is the perfect working example:

```
String reverseHebrew(String text) {
    text = text.splitMapJoin(
      RegExp(r'[\u0590-\u05FF]+'),
      onMatch: (m) => m.group(0).split('').reversed.join(),
      onNonMatch: (string) => string,
    );
    // reverse words in string
    return text.split(' ').reversed.join(' ');
  }
```